# Is it possible to have a gas so dense a solid or liquid can be formed on top?

Tags: physical-chemistry

any ideas? I’ve been wondering about this for a while.

Thanks

Comment: I ‘any ideas’ your question? Please elaborate

Answer (score 3):

Li weighs 0.534g/ml, Ar already 0.536g/ml at it's critical point, Kr 0.9.

So: Yes.